# Apply regex formatting to list of terms to match with pandas column

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have the following DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'phrase':['websocket internet is loading','foo bar kangeroo bunny','websocket funny internet','scrape the internet with websocket','another one']})

df
    phrase
0   websocket internet is loading
1   foo bar kangeroo bunny
2   websocket funny internet
3   scrape the internet with websocket
4   another one
```

I am trying to use regex with Pandas' `str.contains()` to match phrases with multiple words, but not requiring the exact sequence of those words to match. I would like to match using a list of strings:
`['websocket internet', 'foo bunny']`.

Expected output:

```
0     True
1     True
2     True
3     True
4    False
```

I know I can implement regex like so:

```
df['phrase'].str.contains(r'^(?=.*\bfoo\b)(?=.*\bbunny\b).*$')
df['phrase'].str.contains(r'^(?=.*\bwebsocket\b)(?=.*\binternet\b).*$')
```

But what if I have a large list of match terms? How would I format all of those strings to the necessary regex, and is there a way for me to implement multiple regex in one `str.contains()` function?

Comment: Do your search terms always contain two words?

Comment: If you have whitespace boundaries only, try this: `search = ['websocket internet', 'foo bunny']`, then create the single word list with `search = [f' {x} ' for l in search for x in l.split()]` and then do the search with `df['phrase'].apply(lambda x: any(l for l in search if l in f' {x} '))`

Comment: So, did  you have a chance to try it out?

Comment: @Wouter no, there are singular words too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your word boundaries are whitespace boundaries, you can use

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'phrase':['websocket internet is loading','foo bar kangeroo bunny','websocket funny internet','scrape the internet with websocket','another one']})
search = ['websocket internet', 'foo bunny']
search = [f' {x} ' for l in search for x in l.split()]
df['phrase'].apply(lambda x: any(l for l in search if l in f' {x} '))
# => 0     True
#    1     True
#    2     True
#    3     True
#    4    False
```

*Details*:

- `search = [f' {x} ' for l in search for x in l.split()]` splits out all non-whitespace chunks from the `search` list and appends an extra space on both side so as to search for an exact word
- `df['phrase'].apply(lambda x: any(l for l in search if l in f' {x} '))` goes through all values in the `phrase` column and marks as True those that contain at least one item from the `search` list. An extra space is added to both start and end of each search string.